# ¿Como modificar un archivo de texto?

Tags: java

Hola espero me puedan ayudar lo que pasa es que tengo un archivo de texto (.txt)  donde tengo almacenado un lista de productos con  su nombre, cantidad de ese producto y precio  y ejecuto un programa donde se me despliega un panel con JRadioButton con el nombre del producto y precio y lo que deseo hacer es que cuando el usuario elija algún producto del panel en el archivo de texto me reste  la cantidad de ese producto osea uno menos que fue el que el usuario selecciono ademas de que cuando llegue a 0 este producto se borre del archivo de texto espero me  puedan ayudar ayudar.

Comment: Hola, ¿que has intentando? ¿donde te has atascado?.

Comment: Hola que tal pues tengo lo siguiente tengo una clase donde se me despliega en un panel las opciones de venta con su precio de ahi hago que el usuario seleccione algun producto y esa seleccion la almaceno en un archivo de texto  y tengo otro archivo de texto donde tengo almacenado el producto y la cantidad que tengo